# Memory corruption in python

Tags: python, memory, pyramid

I am deploying my project on python-pyramid with [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) python version 2.7.5. Now during processing I'm getting memory leak error. This error is appearing for first time. On other server with system python 2.7.3, this error doesn't occur.

I have seen other post suggesting to capture memory dump with tool like valgrind. But I'm not sure how to use it with python-pyramid.

Memory dump is very big and stackoverflow is not allowing me to post here. So it is available in http://pastebin.com/atUW89eX

Any suggestions ?

Update:

1. We have installed python-uno using apt-get but we need uno under python2.7.5 under pyenv. So we copied uno.py and unohelper.py from Python2.7.3 to Python2.7.5.
2. According to [this](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/armhf/python-uno/1:3.5.7-0ubuntu5) libreoffice support Python2.7.5.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of potential issues with pyuno:

1. Wrong python version. You must use the exact same point version of python as comes with soffice. You must also compile with the same unicode option (i.e. UCS4 or UCS2).
2. The pyuno interface is not enormously robust. You must only pass **byte streams** and not **unicode streams**.

Those are the big ones. You also need the basics, like having the correct LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PYTHONPATH.

Comment: I have updated the question and from the link I believe the current installed version of python-uno works with Python2.7.3 and Python2.7.5. Am I correct?

Comment: @cisnik No, it must be the exact point version. I can't guarantee that alone will solve the problem, but it's necessary to eliminate that as one of the sources of error. You should also post the code that's causing this, in case it's a type mismatch.

Answer (score -1):

The error occurs in a call to `pyuno`, which wraps native code of libreoffice.

I assume you create/modify a document via pyuno/libreoffice. IMHO you should debug the program statement by statement where pyuno gets involved (e.g. by commenting out statements and running the program). This or get libreoffice libs with debug info.

From the signature, my guess is that you're passing around a string object which is supposed to be unicode and it's not.

Comment: It's much more likely that the issue is that the object passed is unicode, and not bytes.